# Xcode 11 project, when trying to archive the version is reset just before archive ends

Tags: swift, xcode, archive, testflight

I am suspecting a permission issue. my Dev id has App Manager access, and should be able to submit a new version. After updating the App to swift4 using Xcode 11, I try to submit a new version for uploading to testFlight..

I can successfully update the version from Target -> General -> Identity -> Version , and set it to version to 3.0.0
however, after the archive process done ( with Generic iOS device selected as build only device ), the version is reset back to 2.4.3.

In the signing and capabilities, I am using automatic signing with the company team, and in Signing certificate: Apple Development: Akram Husseini (xxxxxxxxx)
Provisioning profile is : Xcode managed profile.

Update: added picture to show build phases run script

[build phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6PoQ.png)

Comment: Have you tried changing the version directly in the Info.plist?

Comment: Yes, same thing happens. as soon as compile finishes, it resets version back to 2.4.3. I Still managed to upload version 2.4.3 to the app store somehow, even though a version 2.5.0 exists. however, not sure what will happen if I try again, the next time we want to release a version to testing.

Comment: Maybe you have some sort of build or archive script that is setting up a version? Check your schemes and your build phases.

Comment: I Updated the post to include a picture showing build phase, i found one script to be running there, not sure what it does

Comment: there was a bash build script, thanks Roberto... have to do my updates there thanks..

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. My current version is 2.0.11. I have changed it to 2.0.12 from info.plist, but after archive its resetting back to 2.0.11 again.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

there was a batch script, thanks Roberto for your help..